# Copying PostgreSQL Server to Another Server

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, database-migration, data-migration

I'm looking to copy a PostgreSQL Server to Another server.

1. I want to migrate entire server which might contain multiple databases
2. I am trying to do it with cloud databases (e.g. AWS which doesn't provide super user privileges for RDS) so it would be better to provide a solution with Users of attribute Create role, Create DB
   Password valid until infinity

I want something like (This query doesn't exists just an example)

```
pg_dumpall -C -h localhost -U localuser | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser
```

I know that below query exists but it is does not work same for pg_dumpall

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```

Comment: [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.htm) does exist. `-C` switch doesn't but it's unnecessary: the resulting script already includes `create database` statements.

Comment: @Zegarek I know pg_dumpall exists, I wanted to say pg_dumpall query for my specific task doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, it took me a few re-reads of the question. You mean you want to move all databases, *except for one specific database* - does that sound correct?

Comment: @Zegarek sorry for the confusion I caused, my problem is that I want to Migrate entire Database Server which contains multiple databases, (Most of the solutions include migrating a single database like this query : pg_dump -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname. which I didn't want)

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77301060/5298879) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to move all databases from cluster A to cluster B, except for one specific database on cluster A, you can add the `--exclude-database=pattern` parameter to [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.htm):

> `--exclude-database=pattern`
>
> Do not dump databases whose name matches ***pattern***. Multiple patterns can be excluded by writing multiple `--exclude-database` switches. The pattern parameter is interpreted as a ***pattern*** according to the same rules used by psql's `\d` commands (see [Patterns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS)), so multiple databases can also be excluded by writing wildcard characters in the pattern. When using wildcards, be careful to quote the pattern if needed to prevent shell wildcard expansion.

```bash
pg_dumpall -h localhost -U localuser --exclude-database=the_db_you_do_not_want \ 
| psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser
```

As mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300464/copying-postgresql-server-to-another-server?noredirect=1#comment136276355_77300464), `-C` doesn't exist for this command because it's unnecessary. The `--clean` is optional and not really advised as a default - if you misdirect your command and target the wrong cluster, it's better for it to warn you than to quietly wipe it clean.

---

Your [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77300464/revisions) fundamentally change the question and [the latest comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300464/copying-postgresql-server-to-another-server#comment136277259_77300464) doesn't really align with the [latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77300464/4) - multi-db dump&restore is what you [initially](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77300464/1) asked about, and that's exactly what `pg_dumpall` is meant to do.

I suspect your problem isn't really about PostgreSQL `psql`, `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall`, it's about how these things are done on AWS RDS. [Here's the official manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.TransportableDB.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
pg_dumpall -c -h localhost -U localuser | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser
```

-c for clean databases before recreating.
also you should have superuser privilege for this user.